# Sqlite query error: Invalid Column Type

Tags: android, sqlite

Database:

```
  db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME_NOTE + " ("
                + BaseColumns._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
                + NoteColumns.TITLE + " NVARCHAR(200),"
                + NoteColumns.NOTE + " TEXT,"
                + NoteColumns.CREATED_DATE + " INTEGER,"
                + NoteColumns.MODIFIED_DATE + " INTEGER,"
                + NoteColumns.TYPE + " INTEGER,"
                + NoteColumns.NEED_NOTICE + " INTEGER,"
                + NoteColumns.NOTICE_WAY + " INTEGER,"
                + NoteColumns.NOTICE_TIME + " INTEGER"
                + ");");
```

here's my query:

```
Cursor cursor = mContext.managedQuery(mContext.getIntent().getData(), 
            NoteEntry.PROJECTION_NOTE,
            null, null, NoteColumns.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER);
```

the code works ok when NoteEntry.PROJECTION_NOTE is

```
public static final String[] PROJECTION_NOTE = new String[] {
    BaseColumns._ID, // 0
    NoteColumns.TITLE, // 1
    NoteColumns.NOTE };
```

but i get the "Invalid column type" exception when i set this

```
public static final String[] PROJECTION_NOTE = new String[] {
    BaseColumns._ID, // 0
    NoteColumns.TITLE, // 1
    NoteColumns.NOTE,
    NoteColumns.CREATED_DATE,
    NoteColumns.MODIFIED_DATE,
    NoteColumns.TYPE,
    NoteColumns.NEED_NOTICE,
    NoteColumns.NOTICE_WAY,
    NoteColumns.NOTICE_TIME
};
```

So confused. 
And another question, should i use INTEGER type to store the Date data as the Created_Date field, the code sample in sdk does. I'm new to sqlite and android.
Pls help me.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Type" is the column name 
and found this way to solve the problem, still don't understand:

```
public static final String[] PROJECTION_NOTE = new String[] {
        BaseColumns._ID, // 0
        NoteColumns.TITLE, // 1
        NoteColumns.NOTE,
        NoteColumns.CREATED_DATE,
        NoteColumns.MODIFIED_DATE,
        NoteColumns.TYPE + " as " + NoteColumns.TYPE,
        NoteColumns.NEED_NOTICE + " as " + NoteColumns.NEED_NOTICE,
        NoteColumns.NOTICE_WAY + " as " + NoteColumns.NOTICE_WAY,
        NoteColumns.NOTICE_TIME + " as " + NoteColumns.NOTICE_TIME,
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the **date** also as **TEXT** type not **INTEGER**  type because the date may contains some special character.

Comment: but in sdk notepad sample, they use INTEGER, and the insert feature also works fine. I thank it is not the problem